# How to set ATTR_USE_CLASSPATH_ONLY_JAR in eclipse without editing launch configuration for Java > 8?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, spring-tool-suite, sts

In eclipse it is possible to specify that jar files be referenced from a temporary JAR to avoid classpath length limitations. This can be achieved by selecting the checkbox in the classpath tab in the run/debug configuration:

[image]

This works great, but this option is no longer exposed when one uses java version greater than 8, as it is illustrated here:

[image]

The tab `classpath` is no longer there. It is replaced by the `Dependencies` tab, which does not expose this checkbox.

However, the reasons why one would need to use it, are still present in post java 8 world. The classpath can get longer than the OS limit, especially in Windows 10 environment, where that limit is much lower (32k) than on Mac/linux (200k+). On Windows 10, this limit can easily be exceeded if one is using spring boot and few other technologies (jackson, rx, kafka, redis, aws, etc.) that are rather standard and ubiquitous in the enterprise development environment.

In a [comment to eclipse bug 558495](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=558495#c51) it is suggested that one manually edits the eclipse launch configuration, and set the value for the key attribute `org.eclipse.jdt.launching.ATTR_USE_CLASSPATH_ONLY_JAR` to `true`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.localJavaApplication">
  <listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_PATHS">
    <listEntry value="/demoapp/src/main/java/demo/DemoApplication.java"/>
  </listAttribute>
  <listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_TYPES">
    <listEntry value="1"/>
  </listAttribute>
  <booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.ATTR_EXCLUDE_TEST_CODE" value="true"/>
  <booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.ATTR_USE_CLASSPATH_ONLY_JAR" value="true"/>
  <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.MAIN_TYPE" value="demo.DemoApplication"/>
  <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.MODULE_NAME" value="demoapp"/>
  <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROGRAM_ARGUMENTS" value="--spring.profiles.active=dev"/>
  <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROJECT_ATTR" value="demoapp"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

That works, but it is inconvenient to say the least. Whenever any change is made to launch configuration, the manually set value gets reset to `false`, so one has to open the launch configuration that lives in `<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core` directory and edit it again. Besides being inconvenient, this process is also error prone, and less than desirable, as one is modifying the files that eclipse is managing.

Is there a way to do it from within eclipse's UI? Is there some other (better?) way to deal with the long classpaths in eclipse?

Several months ago I reported the issue in eclipse's bugzilla [bug 561218](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=561218), but so far it got no traction.

Comment: Please avoid reporting something non-critical as critical. Instead, try to provide a patch for it or at least more details that might be helpful to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The temporary JAR file trick to work around line length limitation in Windows may work in your case, but not in all cases when using Java 9 or higher.

Instead, for Java 9 or higher [using an ***@argfile*** will be supported starting with Eclipse 2020-12](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.18/jdt.php#launch-with-argfile) (which will be released on 16 December 2020) for that. The *@argfile* option can be found in the *Arguments* tab.

Comment: Sadly, there is still a problem with this approach, and the bug is still not fixed, 10 months after being reported. May be to some people this is not a critical bug, but it is nevertheless important, as it directly affects the key usability of the otherwise outstanding product. Happy to test the fix and/or work directly with the developers if that helps.

Comment: @xbranko Which bug? For Java 8 and lower Eclipse provides using a temporary JAR file and for Java 9 and higher there is the _@argfile_ option. So for every Java version there is a way to work around line length limitation on Windows.

Comment: This is the [bug] (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=561218). If you'd like we can continue the discussion over there as well.

Comment: @xbranko I can not reproduce it either. Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the bug report or close it. The relevant thing here is the Java version you use to run it (specified in the launch configuration), not the compiler compliance level of the project. And by the way, it's a no-go to tell it's causing pain and report it as critical, even though there's a workaround and currently you're the only one seeing it (even after three person spent their time to help you for free).

Comment: this issue did not solve for me even after editing launch file. Not sure what to do

Comment: @ManishBansal Please ask this as a new question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and information about your launch configuration, including what you edited why.